# A simple proof about balls in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

How do you prove formally that $x+B(0,r)=B(x,r)$ and $yB(0,r)=B(0,yr)$ ,where $x\in \mathbb{R}$ , $y,r>0$ ?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
x+B(0,r)&=\{x+y:|y|<r\}\\
&=\{z:|z-x|<r\}&\text{, where z=x+y}\\
&=B(x,r)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
yB(0,r)&=\{yx:|x|<r\}\\
&=\{z:\left|\frac{z}{y}\right|<r\}&\text{, where z=xy}\\
&=\{z:|z|<|y|r\}\\
&=B(0,|y|r)\\
&=B(0,yr)&\text{, since y>0}
\end{align}

Comment: In the general case, where $B(0,r)={x|d(0,x)<r}$ ?

Comment: I'm sorry, what is your question? What do you want to know about the general case? And what is the general case? What you wrote is a definition, not a general case...

Answer (score 1):

$x+B(0,r)=\{x+y\ |\ y\in B(0,r)\}$. Take $z\in x+B(0,r)$. Then $z=x+y$ for some $y\in B(0,r)$, that is, $|y|<r$. Hence, $|z-x|=|x+y-x|=|y|<r$, so $z\in B(x,r)$. The reverse direction is similar, and the other assertion goes analogously.